# Analysis class diagram - associating classes

Tags: class, uml, associations, diagram, analysis

**New user so I can't post images. Image link provided below:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXf0G.jpg

This is for a walk-in booking system not an online reservation system.

**Normal Booking scenario:**

User/Member gives information to receptionist. Users can book up to a month in-advance.

Receptionist searches user/member info. Receptionist must be logged in to search user/member or make a booking.

if details are found the booking continues as normal, if not user details are added to the users file.

Booking time/date/type is then checked for availability. If available then a booking is made.

**Extra:**

There are two types of staff account 'normal-user' (Receptionist) and 'admin' (Manager).

Manager can reset staff account passwords and create new staff accounts.

Manager can edit session details on the timetable (time, date, type) etc. Do i need a timetable class here??

Comment: Umm... What exactly is your question? Are you just asking if the diagram you linked to matches your limited requirements?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 

Yes, I just wanted to know if my associations/generalisations were correct thus far?

And also if I would need to create a timetable class for the swimming pool timetable?

Comment: Is this homework? People usually don't worry about whether their diagrams are technically right in practice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer that, we would need a much more developed specification.

I would suggest you develop with what you have, meeting only the minimum requirements for each iteration. Then, if you find your users *need* a timetable of some sort, then add it at that point.

In general, don't add more complexity than you need until you know you need it. The more moving parts a system has, the harder it is to maintain and use and to put together in the first place. Get the application up and functioning and in the users' hands. Until you get real feedback from them, you are just taking stabs in the dark. Let the users' tell you what they need and want.